# SQL Select all if parameter is empty

Tags: sql, string, select, case, where-clause

I'm looking for a solution that allow me select all records in a
column if the parameter is empty.  (see where clause section).
The empty parameters are in the Tempdb and I can't create Store Procedures.

```
SELECT

DB_NAME(),
ST.ID,
ST.DESC,
SP.DESC,
TF.STARTDATE,
TF.TERMDate

FROM STANDA ST      --1st DB  -can't create procedures
LEFT JOIN TABLEFEE TF ON TF.TABLEFEE = ST.ID    --1st DB  -can't create procedures
LEFT JOIN SPECIAL SP ON SP.SPECIALC = TF.SPECIALC               --1st DB  -can't create procedures


-- EACH FILTER SHOULD SELECT ALL IF PARAMETER IS EMPTY IN THE BELOW SELECT STATEMENT ENCLOSED WITH 
((SELECT...))
WHERE ST.DESC IN 
((SELECT ME_Desc FROM ##ME_DATA WHERE ME_ID = @@Counter))   --##ME_DATA  2nd DB (temp)
AND SP.DESC IN 
((SELECT ME_Special FROM ##ME_DATA WHERE ME_ID = @@Counter))
AND  TF.STARTDATE IN
((SELECT ME_STARTDate FROM ##ME_Data WHERE ME_ID = @@Counter))
AND TF.TERMDATE IN
((SELECT ME_TERMDate FROM ##ME_Data WHERE ME_ID = @@Counter))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
(SELECT ME_Desc FROM ##ME_DATA WHERE ME_ID = @@Counter OR @@Counter IS NULL)
```

Although where you use "IS NULL" may depend on exactly what the data type of @@Counter is ... you say "empty", but potentially it could be a numeric value that will either be zero or a valid number - therefore OR @@Counter = 0 might be more applicable.  Also, you haven't specified exactly which database platform you are using, so you should be able to adapt the syntax as required for your situation, if necessary.

Alternatively:

```
WHERE (
  @@Counter IS NULL
  OR
  (ST.DESC IN 
      ((SELECT ME_Desc FROM ##ME_DATA WHERE ME_ID = @@Counter)))
)
```